# Qt / C++ - "Including" a header file causes a LOT of errors (spam)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having some problems with my script. Everything was fine for a while but now when I `#include` a file I get errors that occur on any line pointing to another class. Like these (there's actually 12 of them..):

`x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:20: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'`

`x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:20: error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Occurs when I say `InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;`

Edit: the include I can't put in the header is inkspot.h in the inkpuppet.h header.

For each pointer I get the two above errors x3.

Then I get errors because obviously the pointers no longer work.

I'm going to go ahead and post all my code because I do not know which parts will be relevant.

inkpuppet.h

```
#ifndef INKPUPPET_H
#define INKPUPPET_H

#include "inkspot.h"
//#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class InkPuppet;
}

class InkPuppet : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InkPuppet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkPuppet();

    Ui::InkPuppet *ui;

private slots:
    void setMinimum(int value);
    void setMaximum(int value);
    void actionNew();
    void actionAbout();
    void setSpacing(int);
    void on_colorAButton_clicked();
};

#endif // INKPUPPET_H
```

inkpuppet.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"
#include "newdialog.h"
#include "aboutdialog.h"
#include "inkspot.h"


#include <Qt>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QColorDialog>


InkPuppet::InkPuppet(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InkPuppet)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //connect the frame range boxes to the timeslider
    connect(ui->lowerFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setMinimum(int)));
    connect(ui->upperFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setMaximum(int)));

    //connect tool palette items
    connect(ui->spacingBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setSpacing(int)));

    connect(ui->colorAButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_colorAButton_clicked()));

    //connect the menu items
    connect(ui->actionNew, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionNew()));
    connect(ui->actionAbout, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionAbout()));

}

void InkPuppet::setMinimum(int value)
{
    ui->timeSlider->setMinimum(value);
    ui->frameNumberBox->setMinimum(value);
}

void InkPuppet::setMaximum(int value)
{
    ui->timeSlider->setMaximum(value);
    ui->frameNumberBox->setMaximum(value);
}


void InkPuppet::setSpacing(int)
{
    InkSpot *spot = new InkSpot(this);
    //spot->puppet = this;
    spot->spacing = ui->spacingBox->value();
}

//menu items
void InkPuppet::actionNew()
{
    NewDialog *nDialog = new NewDialog;
    //nDialog->createNew(this);
    nDialog->pointerToPuppet = this;
    nDialog->setModal(true);

    nDialog->show();

}

void InkPuppet::actionAbout()
{
    AboutDialog *aDialog = new AboutDialog;
    aDialog->setModal(true);
    aDialog->show();
}


//tool menu
void InkPuppet::on_colorAButton_clicked()
{
//    QColor color = QColorDialog(QColor->setRgb(255, 0, 0));
//    //color->setRgb(0, 0, 0);
//    qDebug() << "done";
//    if(color->isValid())
//    {

//        QString qss = QString("background-color: %1").arg(color->name());
//        ui->colorAButton->setStyleSheet(qss);
//    }
}


InkPuppet::~InkPuppet()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

inkspot.h

```
#ifndef INKSPOT_H
#define INKSPOT_H

#include "newdialog.h"
//#include "inkpuppet.h"

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QImage>


namespace Ui {
class InkSpot;
}

class InkSpot : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InkSpot(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void draw(QPainter *painter);
    QWidget *widget;
    int canvasWidth;
    int canvasHeight;
    float spacing;
    NewDialog *newDialog;
    QPixmap pixmap;

signals:
    //int sendWidthOfCanvas();
    //void sendHeightOfCanvas();

public slots:
    //void widthOfCanvas();
    //void heightOfCanvas();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);


private:
    void drawLineTo(const QPoint &endPoint);
    bool drawing;
    QPoint lastPoint;
    QImage image;
    QImage test2;


    Ui::InkSpot *ui;

};

#endif // INKSPOT_H
```

inkspot.cpp

```
#include "inkspot.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include "newdialog.h"
#include "ui_newdialog.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

InkSpot::InkSpot(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    widget = this;
    drawing = false;
    //spacing = puppet->ui->spacingBox->value();
    spacing = 1;//puppet->ui->spacingBox->value();
}

void InkSpot::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        lastPoint = event->pos();
        drawing = true;
    }
}

void InkSpot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && drawing)
    {
        drawLineTo(event->pos());
    }
}

void InkSpot::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && drawing)
    {
        drawLineTo(event->pos());
        drawing = false;
    }
}

void InkSpot::drawLineTo(const QPoint &endPoint)
{
    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);

    QFile *stencilInput; // file for input, assumes a SQUARE RAW 8 bit grayscale image, no JPG no GIF, no size/format header, just 8 bit values in the file
    char *brushPrototype; // raw brush prototype
    uchar *brushData; // raw brush data

    stencilInput = new QFile("C:/brush3.raw");  // open raw file
    stencilInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in;
    in.setDevice(stencilInput);
    int size = stencilInput->size();  // set size to the length of the raw file

    brushPrototype = new char[size];  // create the brush prototype array
    in.readRawData(brushPrototype, size);  // read the file into the prototype
    brushData = new uchar[size];  // create the uchar array you need to construct QImage

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        brushData[i] = (uchar)brushPrototype[i];  // copy the char to the uchar array

    QImage test(brushData, 128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8); // create QImage from the brush data array
     // 128x128 was my raw file, for any file size just use the square root of the size variable provided it is SQUARE
    QImage test2(128, 128, QImage::Format_ARGB32);


   QVector<QRgb> vectorColors(256);  // create a color table for the image
    for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
        vectorColors[c] = qRgb(c, c, c);

    test.setColorTable(vectorColors);  // set the color table to the image

    for (int iX = 0; iX < 128; ++iX)  // fill all pixels with 255 0 0 (red) with random variations for OIL PAINT effect
    // use your color of choice and remove random stuff for solid color
    // the fourth parameter of setPixel is the ALPHA, use that to make your brush transparent by multiplying by opacity 0 to 1
    {
        for (int iY = 0; iY < 128; ++iY)
        {
            test2.setPixel(iX, iY, qRgba(255, 100, 100, (255-qGray(test.pixel(iX, iY)))*0.5));
        }
    }
    // final convertions of the stencil and color brush
    QPixmap testPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(test2);
    QPixmap testPixmap2 = QPixmap::fromImage(test);

    painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    // in a paint event you can test out both pixmaps
//    QLineF line = QLineF(lastPoint, endPoint);
//    float lineLength = line.length();
//    qDebug() << line.length();
//    line.setLength(100.01f);
//    qDebug() << line.length();

    QPainterPath path = QPainterPath(lastPoint);
    path.lineTo(endPoint);
    //qDebug() << path.currentPosition();
    //qDebug() << path.length();
    qreal length = path.length();
    qreal pos = 0;

    while (pos < length)
    {
        qreal percent = path.percentAtLength(pos);
        painter.drawPixmap(path.pointAtPercent(percent).x() - 16, path.pointAtPercent(percent).y() - 16, 32, 32, testPixmap);
        pos += spacing;
    }


    //painter.drawPixmap(line.p1().x() - 16, line.p1().y() - 16, 32, 32, testPixmap);

    //delete all dynamically allocated objects with no parents
    delete [] brushPrototype;
    delete [] brushData;
    delete stencilInput;


    lastPoint = endPoint;

}


void InkSpot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    QRect rect = event->rect();
    painter.drawPixmap(rect, pixmap, rect);

    qDebug() << spacing;

    update();

}
```

newdialog.h

```
#ifndef NEWDIALOG_H
#define NEWDIALOG_H

//#include "ui_newdialog.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class NewDialog;
}

class NewDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~NewDialog();
    InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;
    Ui::NewDialog *ui;

public slots:
    //void createNew(InkPuppet *existingPuppet);
    void createNew();

};

#endif // NEWDIALOG_H
```

newdialog.cpp

```
#include "newdialog.h"
#include "ui_newdialog.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"
#include "inkspot.h"


#include <QDebug>
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>


NewDialog::NewDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NewDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(createNew()));
    //connect(ui->buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(createNew(InkPuppet*)));

}

void NewDialog::createNew()
{
    InkSpot *ink;
    ink = new InkSpot();
    ink->newDialog = this;
    pointerToPuppet->ui->canvas->addWidget(ink->widget);
    //QSize size = pointerToPuppet->ui->canvas->sizeHint();
    ink->widget->resize(ui->widthBox->value(), ui->heightBox->value());
    pointerToPuppet->ui->scrollCanvasItems->resize(ui->widthBox->value(), ui->heightBox->value());
    //pointerToPuppet->ui->canvas->setAlignment(ink->widget, Qt::AlignAbsolute);
    ink->pixmap = QPixmap(QSize(ui->widthBox->value(), ui->heightBox->value()));
    close();
}

NewDialog::~NewDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "inkspot.h"
#include "newdialog.h"
#include "aboutdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    InkPuppet w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried trimming down your code to a minimal example that exhibits the problem but isn't 1000 lines of code?

Comment: If you had read the post you'd see that I said I have no clue where the error is occuring, at this point it's all relevant.

Comment: I read the post, but it should be obvious that the error occurs somewhere around `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:20`, which means line 20. Try to trim surrounding lines as much as possible. Try to comment out include files. If the error vanishes, the error must be in the line you just commented out. If it's an include file, rinse and repeat inside that file. Also @Mat: Nice spot!

Comment: @Mat: That's the end of a namespace, not a class.

Comment: @Mat I can't find anywhere that NewDialog is missing a semicolon, I'm looking in the header file but it already has a semi colon there as well as in the code I've posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have circular dependencies.  "inkpuppet.h" includes "inkspot.h", which includes "newdialog.h", which includes "inkpuppet.h".  Use forward declarations instead, where you can.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @arne: There's an implied "this is the cause of your problem" in my answer, because it almost certainly is.

Comment: Well, actually, that's not the problem. See Mat's comment on the question. Your point is valid, but doesn't help the OP solve his problem.

Comment: @arne: I saw Mat's comment. See my response to it. And yes, since fixing the circular dependency will fix the problem, it most certainly helps. You have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Can I get an explanation on the remaining downvote, mystery voter?

Answer (score 4):

You have circular includes, that are prevented by your header guardians. This means that in your newdialog.h the line `#include "inkpuppet.h"` does nothing, resulting in the `InkPuppet` class is not declared. You need to replace the include line by a forward declaration `class InkPuppet;` and don't forget to include the file in the cpp (in that case, you've got it already).

EDIT: You have to be careful with the namespaces as well, you've got all your classes in two namespaces (global and Ui).